# Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'Interface1 | Interface2 | {}'. Property 'xxx' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: react-typescript, react-state

This is the simplified version of my react component. The inputs are rendered based on value of `isCase1`. The state `formContent` can be either `AddressForm` or `PhoneForm`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface AddressForm {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

interface PhoneForm {
  name: string;
  phoneNumber: number;
}

const Example = () => {
  let isCase1 = true;

  const [formContent, setformContent] = useState<AddressForm | PhoneForm | {}>(
    {}
  );

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="name" value={formContent.name} />
      {isCase1 ? (
        <input type="text" name="name" value={formContent.address} />
      ) : (
        <input
          type="number"
          name="phoneNumber"
          value={formContent.phoneNumber}
        />
      )}
    </form>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

The problem is, in the value attribute of the inputs, `formContent.name`,  `formContent.address`, `formContent.phoneNumber` are giving me similar errors saying:

```
Property 'phoneNumber' does not exist on type '{} | AddressForm | PhoneForm'.
  Property 'phoneNumber' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

How can I specify the types here to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use this approach where you only use one interface and give the optional mark on the properties. Something like this.

```js
interface Form {
  name: string;
  address?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;
}
```

Then you only add one interface to the `useState` types.

```js
  const [formContent, setformContent] = useState<Form>({});
```

And you should define the `formContent` properties in `useState`

```js
  useState<Form>(
    {
      name: '',
      address: '',
      phoneNumber: 0,
    }
  )
```

So, whatever condition of `isCase1` is, the interface will always accept the values of your form.

Comment: That would work, but later when I post the forms, the dto might not look very clean...

Comment: If you want to keep your `formContent` dynamic, you can use this approach where you handle the data that comes in to your state object on every submit. I have an example snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-phoebe-t9pcfn?file=/src/App.tsx)